# Why is this only centering when I'm zoomed in? (using bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If you put the below code in fullscreen, the elements are only centering on the page once I'm zoomed in enough. How can I make it so it's centered regardless?

```css
.col-centered {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.col-centered table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='quiz-list'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4 col-centered'>

        This text should be centered and the table underneath should be centered as well

        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Bootstrap.

The default value for `width` on a `.col-md-4` is `33.3333%`. So, since the div doesn't have float or margins or anything, it is simply aligned to the left side of the screen, and the content inside it is centred all right, but that isn't noticeable.

One solution is to remove the `col-md-4` class.

```css
.col-centered {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.col-centered table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='quiz-list'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-centered'> <!-- this -->

        This text should be centered and the table underneath should be centered as well

        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried other solutions as well, such as setting the width or the margins explicitly, but that doesn't seem to work.

Edit:
Oh, I see why the other solutions don't work: because in this snippet the Bootstrap css is loaded after the style block in the page.
Under normal circumstances, putting things in a stylesheet after loading the Bootstrap stylesheet will work fine to override it. So you can use `width:auto` or `margin:0 auto`, whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I'm not 100% sure I understand what you said at the end. I want the `col-md-4` there because I want that specific width, is there no way to keep that width and have it centered?

Comment: In the stacksnippet, the Bootstrap stylesheet comes after the styles you define yourself. So all the default Bootstrap styles override the ones you put in: your `float:none` becomes `float:left` again etc.

Comment: So what you should do (and what you're probably doing on the real website anyway) is put the link to your own stylesheet after the link to Bootstrap, so your styles will have precedence. Then you can choose whichever method you want, like I said in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In css file, Update

```
.col-centered {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

as

```
.col-centered {
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: why did this fix it?

Comment: Because styles with `!important` override styles without, even if those other styles come later. In most cases, you should try to avoid that though.